# $listeners is readonly. $attrs is readonly errors

Tags: javascript, vue.js, navbar, bootstrap-vue

I am receiving 21 errors like this.

```
 [Vue warn] $listeners is readonly.

found in

---> <RouterLink>
       <BLink>
         <BNavbar>
           <AppNavigation>
             <App> at src/App.vue
               <Root>

vue.js:597 [Vue warn]: $attrs is readonly.

found in

---> <RouterLink>
       <BLink>
         <BNavbar>
           <AppNavigation>
             <App> at src/App.vue
               <Root>
```

I think its related to b-navbar calling vue from another source. When i searched it on the net, I found results asking to change webpack.config.js. Can u please tell me where I can find the webpack.config.js file. Also please let me know if this is not the correct solution.

Navingation:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <b-navbar toggleable="lg" type="dark" variant="dark" fixed="top">
      <b-navbar-brand><router-link to="/" id="ps">Pet-Store</router-link></b-navbar-brand>
           
          <b-navbar-brand><router-link to="/"><img :src=logo id="img"  title="mycompanylogo"></router-link></b-navbar-brand>
          <b-nav-item ><router-link to="/Clinics" id="cl">Clinics</router-link></b-nav-item>
          <b-nav-item><router-link to="/Training" id="tr">Training</router-link></b-nav-item>
          <b-nav-item><router-link to="/Buy-Sell" id="bs">Buy/Sell</router-link></b-nav-item>
          <b-nav-item><router-link to="/Grooming" id="gr"> Grooming</router-link></b-nav-item>
          <b-nav-item><router-link to="/DayCare" id="dc">Day Care</router-link></b-nav-item>
          <b-nav-item><router-link to="/DogWalker" id="dw">Dog Walker</router-link></b-nav-item>
          <b-nav-item v-if="!isLoggedIn"><router-link to="/login" id="si">Sign In</router-link></b-nav-item>
          <b-avatar v-if="isLoggedIn" id="av" variant="light"></b-avatar> 
         <b-nav-item-dropdown v-if="isLoggedIn" :text=user.name right id="log" style="text-decoration:none"> 
          <b-dropdown-item > <b-nav-item v-if="isLoggedIn"><router-link  to="/profile" >My Account</router-link></b-nav-item> </b-dropdown-item>
          <b-dropdown-item > <b-nav-item v-if="isLoggedIn"><a href="" v-on:click.prevent="logoutUser" >Sign out</a></b-nav-item> </b-dropdown-item>
        </b-nav-item-dropdown>
          <b-nav-item><router-link to="/cart"><b-icon icon="cart3" scale="0.75" id="cart-icon"></b-icon></router-link></b-nav-item>
          <p id="item">{{totalItems}}</p>
       
    </b-navbar>
  </div>
</template>
```

I have attached a screenshot of the errors

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CkNZN.png)

Comment: https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs#aliasing-vue-import

Answer (score 1):

the `webpack.config.js` file is usually at the root of your project, if not you can just create it and Webpack will pick it up.

In my case the duplicated instances were caused by some Vue plugins importing the Vue instance differently than how I was doing in my project. I managed to fix it by adding the following to my Webpack config:

```js
    externals: {
      // Stubs out `require('vue')` so it returns `global.Vue`
      vue: 'Vue',
    },
```

Hope it can help anyone struggling with the same issue :)